# External URL to internal images

Tags: 8

Suppose I have a link field for internal images. `$node->file_image->uri` will for instance return:

```
internal:/sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg
```

I need to convert this into an absolute URL for metadata. I can do this manually, of course, but let's see what the usual functions do:

```
file_create_url() = "https://example.com/internal%3A/sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg"
file_build_uri() = "public://internal:/sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg"
file_create_url(file_build_uri()) = "https://example.com/sites/default/files/internal%3A/sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg"
```

No cigar, not even close. The new functions?

```
Url::fromUri()->toString() = "internal:/sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg"
Url::fromUri()->toUriString() = "base:sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg"
```

So, how to do it without doing it manually, of course? Removing `internal:` and prepending `$base_url` is very simple but still a hack.

Comment: You sure your first bit is right? normally an image stored in /sites/default/files/image/image.jpeg would have a uri of internal:/image/image.jpeg (So without the sites/default/files bit as well)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The wording might not be perfect. It isn't an image widget but a link field that accepts an URL and is set to only accept internal references. That's what's inside, yes, and I can handle it everywhere else in twigs and similar with relative ease.

Answer (score 1):

Found it finally:

```
Url::fromUri($node->field_image->uri)->setAbsolute(TRUE)->toString()
```